# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \prod_{m = 1} ^ n \left(1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, contest-math

> Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \prod_{m = 1} ^ n \left(1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2}\right)$

**Attempt $1$:**

$$1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2}=\frac{4m^2-4m+5}{4m^2}=\frac{(2m-1)^2+4}{4m^2}=\left(1-\frac1{2m}\right)^2+\frac1{m^2}$$

Don't know what to do with it.

**Attempt $2$:**

Trying to write the terms of the product to see if there is any pattern.

$$\prod_{m = 1} ^ n \left(1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2}\right)=\frac54\cdot\frac{13}{16}\cdot\frac{29}{36}\cdot\frac{53}{64}\cdots$$

The numerator terms have differences $8,16,24$...

Don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Each term is strictly positive, so you can take the $\log$ in your expression, and go back to a sum. That's usually what's done in this type of situation. Though I still have to work out the details, so I'm unsure if that's actually the way to go yet.

Answer (score 17):

We have the Weierstrass product for $\cos$:

$$\cos(\pi z) = \prod_{m=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{4z^2}{(2m-1)^2}\right)$$ valid for all $z\in \Bbb C$.

Setting $z=i$ we get $$\cosh(\pi) = \prod_{m=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{4}{(2m-1)^2}\right)$$

We also have the Wallis product:

$$\prod_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(2m)^2}{(2m-1)(2m+1)} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Then

\begin{align}
n\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{5}{4m^2}\right)&=n\prod_{m=1}^n\left(\frac{(2m-1)^2+4}{(2m)^2}\right)\\
&=n\prod_{m=1}^n\left(\frac{(2m-1)^2+4}{(2m-1)^2}\right)\prod_{m=1}^n\left(\frac{(2m-1)^2}{(2m)^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{n}{2n+1}\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1+\frac{4}{(2m-1)^2}\right)\prod_{m=1}^n\left(\frac{(2m-1)(2m+1)}{(2m)^2}\right)\\
&\underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}\cosh(\pi)\frac{2}{\pi}  = \frac{\cosh(\pi)}{\pi}\end{align}

Comment: Damn...you reminded me of cleo

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Who?

Comment: Very nice derivation!

Comment: @jjagmath she was a member who only posted one line answer and no solution to the questions

Answer (score 10):

This is only a partial answer which couldn't quite fit as a comment, but it at least shows that the limit does exist and is not $0$.
We have:
$$\begin{split}
\ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{m} + \frac{5}{4m ^ 2}\right) &= - \left(\left(\frac{1}{m} - \frac{5}{4m ^ 2}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{m} - \frac{5}{4m ^ 2}\right)^2 + o\left(\left(\frac{1}{m} - \frac{5}{4m ^ 2}\right)^2\right)\right)\\
&= - \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{4m^2} + \frac{\varepsilon_m}{m^2}\end{split}$$
for some sequence $(\varepsilon_m)_m$ converging to $0$.
Thus, making the $\frac{1}{m}$ go to the other side and after summing from $m = 1$ to $n$:
$$\sum_{m=1}^n \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{m} + \frac{5}{4m ^ 2}\right) + \frac{1}{m} = \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{1}{m^2}\left(\frac{1}{4} + \varepsilon_m\right)$$
The RHS converges, due to the convergence of $\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2}$, to a limit we'll call $L$, and so by equality the $LHS$ converges to that same $L$.
Therefore, using the fact that we have a known expansion for $H_n := \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{1}{m}$ :
$$\begin{split}\sum_{m=1}^n \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{m} + \frac{5}{4m ^ 2}\right) &= - H_n + L + o(1)\\
&= - \ln n - \gamma + L + o(1)\end{split}$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
This finally gives:
$$\ln\left(n\prod_{m = 1} ^ n \left(1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2}\right)\right) = \ln n + \sum_{m=1}^n \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{m} + \frac{5}{4m ^ 2}\right) = L - \gamma + o(1)$$
Consequently, when taking the $\exp$:
$$n\prod_{m = 1} ^ n \left(1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2}\right) \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} e^{L - \gamma}$$

The problem with my approach however is that I was not able to say anything about that limit $L$, but maybe someone will be able to evaluate that expression.

Comment: Or similarly, $n = \prod_{m=2}^n (1 + \frac{1}{m-1})$, so you could relate the answer to $\prod_{m=2}^\infty (1 + \frac{5}{4m(m-1)})$.

Answer (score 8):

First let's express the partial products in terms of the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$$n\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{5}{4m^2}\right) = n\prod_{m=1}^n\left(\frac{(2m-1)^2+4}{4m^2}\right) = n\prod_{m=1}^n\left(\frac{(m-1/2)^2+1}{m^2}\right)$$
$$=n\prod_{m=1}^n\left(\left(\frac{m-1/2-i}{m}\right)\left(\frac{m-1/2+i}{m}\right)\right)=n\frac{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}-i\right)!\left(n-\frac{1}{2}+i\right)!}{n!^2\left(-\frac{1}{2}-i\right)!\left(-\frac{1}{2}+i\right)!}$$
$$=n\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}-i\right)\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}+i\right)}{\Gamma(n+1)^2\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}-i\right)\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}+i\right)}{\Gamma(n)^2\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{n B\left(n,\frac{1}{2}-i\right)B\left(n,\frac{1}{2}+i\right)} \text{ where } B(\alpha,\beta) \text{ is the Beta function}$$
Now notice that, by Stirling's approximation, we have that [$B(n,z_0)\sim\Gamma(z_0)n^{-z_0}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Approximation)  so
$$\sqrt{n}B\left(n,\frac{1}{2}+i\right)\sqrt{n}B\left(n,\frac{1}{2}-i\right)\sim n\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right)n^{-1/2-i}n^{-1/2+i}$$
$$=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)\Gamma\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)\right)}$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{\cos(i\pi)}=\frac{\pi}{\cosh(\pi)}$$
which let's us compute the limit of the denominator and, thus,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{5}{4m^2}\right) = \frac{\cosh(\pi)}{\pi}=\frac{e^\pi+e^{-\pi}}{2\pi}\quad \square$$

Comment: What's the point of using $\tau$ just to set it equal to $1$ at the end?

Comment: @jjagmath That is because, at first, I was proving a more general result and then I changed it to the particular case $\tau=1$ because I thought there was no point on proving the general case. However, I forgot to change that part. I've already edited it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

**Preliminaries**

The recursive relation for Gamma, $x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$, leads to
$$
\prod_{m=1}^n\frac{m+x}m=\frac{\Gamma(n+1+x)}{n!\Gamma(1+x)}\tag1
$$
A limit that follows from [Gautschi's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautschi%27s_inequality)
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1+x)}{n!\,(n+1)^x}=1\tag2
$$
Thus, we can derive
$$
\begin{align}
&\prod_{m=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac xm\right)\left(1+\frac ym\right)\left(1-\frac {x+y}m\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1+x)}{n!\Gamma(1+x)}\frac{\Gamma(n+1+y)}{n!\Gamma(1+y)}\frac{\Gamma(n+1-x-y)}{n!\Gamma(1-x-y)}\tag{3a}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^x}{\Gamma(1+x)}\frac{(n+1)^y}{\Gamma(1+y)}\frac{(n+1)^{-x-y}}{\Gamma(1-x-y)}\tag{3b}\\
&=\frac1{\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1+y)\Gamma(1-x-y)}\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a):}$ apply $(1)$
$\text{(3b):}$ apply $(2)$
$\text{(3c):}$ take the limit

We will also use [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)
$$
\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\pi\csc(\pi x)\tag4
$$

---

**Computing the Product**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1-\frac1m+\frac5{4m^2}\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\prod_{m=1}^n\frac{m^2-m+\frac54}{m^2}\frac{m+1}m\tag{5a}\\
&=\prod_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\left(m^2-m+\frac54\right)(m+1)}{m^3}\tag{5b}\\
&=\prod_{m=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{\frac12+i}m\right)\left(1-\frac{\frac12-i}m\right)\left(1+\frac1m\right)\tag{5c}\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{\Gamma\!\left(\frac12-i\right)\Gamma\!\left(\frac12+i\right)\Gamma(2)}\tag{5d}\\
&=\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi2-i\pi\right)}\pi\tag{5e}\\[6pt]
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{\cosh(\pi)}\pi}\tag{5f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a):}$ $\prod\limits_{m=1}^n\frac{m+1}m=n+1$
$\text{(5b):}$ $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1$
$\text{(5c):}$ $m^2-m+\frac54=\left(m-\frac12-i\right)\left(m-\frac12+i\right)$
$\text{(5d):}$ apply $(3)$
$\text{(5e):}$ apply $(4)$
$\text{(5f):}$ $\sin\left(\frac\pi2-ix\right)=\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$

---

**Asymptotic Approximation**

Using power series and the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, we can extend Claude Leibovici's asymptotic expansion.
$$
\begin{align}
n\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1-\frac1m+\frac5{4m^2}\right)
&=\frac{n}{n+1}\prod_{m=1}^n\frac{m^2-m+\frac54}{m^2}\frac{m+1}m\tag{6a}\\
&=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-1}\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{4m^2}+\frac5{4m^3}\right)\tag{6b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(6a):}$ $\prod\limits_{m=1}^n\frac{m+1}m=n+1$
$\text{(6b):}$ simplify

Using the power series for $\log(1+x)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
&\log\left(1+\frac1{4m^2}+\frac5{4m^3}\right)\\
&=\frac1{4m^2}+\frac5{4m^3}-\frac1{32m^4}-\frac5{16m^5}-\frac{149}{192m^6}+O\left(\frac1{m^7}\right)\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Applying the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula to $(7)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
&\log\left(\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{4m^2}+\frac5{4m^3}\right)\right)\\
&=\log\left(\frac{\cosh(\pi)}\pi\right)-\frac1{4n}-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac{19}{32n^3}-\frac1{4n^4}+\frac{17}{960n^5}+O\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)\tag8
\end{align}
$$
The Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula adds a constant, which can be determined from $(5)$.

Subtracting the power series for $\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)$ from $(8)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
&\log\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{4m^2}+\frac5{4m^3}\right)\right)\\
&=\log\left(\frac{\cosh(\pi)}\pi\right)-\frac5{4n}+\frac{25}{96n^3}-\frac{35}{192n^5}+O\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)\tag9
\end{align}
$$
Using $(6)$, $(9)$, and the power series for $e^x$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
&n\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1-\frac1m+\frac5{4m^2}\right)\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{\cosh(\pi)}\pi\left(1-\frac5{4n}+\frac{25}{32n^2}-\frac{25}{384n^3}-\frac{1375}{6144n^4}-\frac{35}{8192n^5}+O\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)\right)}\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
The error at $n=3$ is $0.036\%$; at $n=4$, it is $0.006\%$.

Comment: Very clear' clean and nice answer ! Thanks for posting it

Answer (score 4):

If we complex factor your product;

$$\dfrac{(2m - 1)^2 + 4}{4m^2} = \dfrac{(2m - 1)^2 - (2i)^2}{4m^2} = \dfrac{2m - 1 + 2i}{2m} \cdot \dfrac{2m - 1 - 2i}{2m}$$.

Hence, we split into $2$ products:

$$\prod_{m = 1}^{n}{1 - \dfrac{1}{m} + \dfrac{5}{4m^2}} = \prod_{m = 1}^{n}{\dfrac{2m - 1 + 2i}{2m} \cdot \dfrac{2m - 1 - 2i}{2m}} 
\\= \prod_{m = 1}^{n}{\dfrac{2m - 1 + 2i}{2m}} \cdot \prod_{m = 1}^{n}{\dfrac{2m - 1 - 2i}{2m}}$$

> $\displaystyle\prod_{m = 1}^{n}{\dfrac{2m - 1 + k}{2m}} = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{k}{2} + n - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)!}{\left(\dfrac{k}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)! \cdot n!}$

and

> $\displaystyle\prod_{m = 1}^{n}{\dfrac{2m - 1 - k}{2m}} = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{-k}{2} + n - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)!}{\left(\dfrac{-k}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)! \cdot n!}$

Hence,

> $$n\cdot\prod_{m = 1}^{n}{1 - \dfrac{1}{m} + \dfrac{5}{4m^2}} = n\cdot\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{k}{2} + n - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)!}{\left(\dfrac{k}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)! \cdot n!}\cdot\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{-k}{2} + n - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)!}{\left(\dfrac{-k}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)! \cdot n!}$$
> for which the limit approaches $(n \to \infty)$
> $$\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{-k}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)! \cdot \left(\dfrac{k}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)!}$$

---

Substitute $k = 2i$;
$$\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{-2i}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)! \cdot \left(\dfrac{2i}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)!} \\= \dfrac{1}{\Gamma{\left(-i + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)} \cdot \Gamma{\left(i + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)}}$$

Edit;

$$\\= \dfrac{1}{\Gamma{\left(1 - \left(i + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right)} \cdot \Gamma{\left(i + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)}} \\= \dfrac{\sin{\left(\pi\left(i + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right)}}{\pi} = \dfrac{\cos{i\pi}}{\pi} =  \dfrac{\cosh{\pi}}{\pi} \\\quad\\ \\\approx 
3.6898$$

Comment: Note that the expression can be somewhat rewritten using the identity $\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z) = \pi / \sin(\pi z)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ah yes! I cannot believe I missed such an substitution.

Comment: *easy substitution

Answer (score 4):

$$1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2}=\frac {m^2-m+\frac 54}{m^2}=\frac {(m-a)(m-b)}{m^2}$$ where
$$a=\frac 12-i \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac 12+i$$

Using Pochhammer symbols and their equivalents to the gamma function

$$P_n=\prod_{m=1}^n \left(1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2} \right)=\frac{\Gamma (n+1-a) \,\Gamma (n+1-b)}{\Gamma (1-a)\, \Gamma (1-b)\,
   \Gamma (n+1)^2}$$ Replacing partly $a$ and $b$ by their values
$$P_n=\frac{\cosh (\pi )}{\pi }\,\frac{\Gamma (n+a) \,\Gamma (n+b)}{
   \Gamma (n+1)^2}$$ Considering now
$$Q_n=\log\left(n\,\frac{\pi }{\cosh (\pi )}\,P_n\right)$$ and using Stirling approximation
$$Q_n=-\frac{5}{4 n}\left(1-\frac{5}{24 n^2}+\frac{7}{48 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)\right)$$ Back to $P_n$
$$n\,P_n=\frac{\cosh (\pi )}{\pi }\,\left(1-\frac{5}{4 n}+\frac{25}{32 n^2}-\frac{25}{384
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$  which is a good approximation even for small values of $n$. For example, the absolute relative error is $0.045$% for $n=5$.

Comment: (+1) I've added a section on computing the asymptotic approximation by a different method.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$n \prod_{m = 1} ^ n \left(1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2}\right)=e^{\log n +\sum_{m = 1} ^ n \log\left(1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2}\right)}$$

and

$$\sum_{m = 1} ^ n \log\left(1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2}\right)=\log \frac 5 4+\sum_{m = 2} ^ n \log\left(1 - \frac1m \right)+\sum_{m = 2} ^ n \log\left(1 + \frac5{4m ^ 2-4m}\right)$$

with

$$\sum_{m = 2} ^ n \log\left(1 - \frac1m \right)=-\log n $$

and [numerically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+log%281+%2B+5%2F%284+%28-1+%2B+m%29+m%29%29+for+m%3D2..1000000)

$$\sum_{m = 2} ^ n \log\left(1 + \frac5{4m ^ 2-4m}\right)\to s\approx 1.0824\tag 1$$

therefore

$$n \prod_{m = 1} ^ n \left(1 - \frac1m + \frac5{4m ^ 2}\right)\to e^{s+\log \frac 54}=\frac 54 e^{s}\approx 3.68$$

---

Finally, using the fine [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4714423/505767) given by jjagmath, now we are able to find a closed form for $(1)$, indeed

$$\prod_{m = 2} ^ n \left(1 + \frac5{4m ^ 2-4m}\right)=\prod_{m = 2} ^ n \frac{4m ^ 2-4m+5}{4m ^ 2-4m}=\prod_{m = 2} ^ n \frac{(2m-1)^2+4}{(2m-1)^2}\frac{(2m-1)^2}{2m(2m-2)}=$$

$$=\prod_{m = 2} ^ n \left(1+\frac{4}{(2m-1)^2}\right)\frac2{\displaystyle \prod_{m = 2} ^ n\frac{4(m-1)^2}{4(m-1)^2-1}} \to e^s=\frac15\cosh(\pi) \frac 4 \pi =\frac 4 5 \frac{\cosh(\pi)}{\pi}$$

which leads to the limit $\frac{\cosh(\pi)}{\pi}$.